# I want to retrieve the contact photo for my contacts. How do i go about it?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I am using the code below to access the phone numbers and the names of the contact. I want to add to this function a way to also add the photo of the contact.

```
void loadContacts() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                Cursor cursor2 = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    make_contact(name,phoneNumber);
                }
                cursor2.close();
            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: follow this link https://gist.github.com/evandrix/7058235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bitmap Image,

```
private Bitmap retrieveContactPhoto(String contactID) {

            Bitmap photo = null;

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                }

                assert inputStream != null;
                inputStream.close();

               return photo ;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
```

By using contact Id you can retrieve bitmap image and set to imageview.

Comment: use this Long.valueOf(contactID) instead this new Long(contactID).

Comment: Also this code creating NullPointerException when closing the inputStream.close(); Do a null check before closing the IOstream.